# angular append everywhere last compiled element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im trying to add custom event in fullcallendar plugin.

```
eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
    scope.tmp = {
       time: $time,
       $title: $title,
       crest: event.clubCrest,
       statusKey: statusKey
    };
    scope.data = angular.copy(scope.tmp);
    template = $compile("<event-label data="{{data}}" ></event-label>"))(scope);
     return eventElement.find("div.fc-content").append(template);
```

scope.data provide separate data to directive, but appended are directive with only last delivered data to eventLabel directive. How to separate these directives? Is there something im doing wrong?

```
angular.module('acc.directives').directive 'eventLabel', () ->
  templateUrl: 'dist/views/commons/directives/calendar/customEvent/eventLabel/template.html'
  restrict: 'E'
  scope: {}
  link: (scope, element, attribute) ->
    scope.data = angular.fromJson(attribute.data)
    console.log(scope.data);  //this console log returns last provided data
```

Comment: As each event gets rendered you are overwriting `scope.data`. Try making `scope.data` an object  and use the event id as keys

Answer (score 0):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJqJ-0U74IY) solved my case.

Shortly:

   The `{{}}` braces throw data thru reference, so there is nothing weird about that passed different data to directive got the same (lastly passed) data.
Solution was pass it like

```
data = JSON.stringify(scope.tmp);
template = $compile("<event-label data='" + data + "'></event-label>")(scope);
return eventElement.find("div.fc-content").append(template);
```

then in directive 
`scope.data = angular.fromJson(attribute.data);`